# what does images:Array<Object> = []; mean in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I just came across this statement in typescript

```
 images:Array<Object> = [];
```

what does the "<>" mean ?.

Comment: an empty array of objects. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) and it's a way to specify the type of the elements in the array.

This:

```
let images: Array<Object> = [];
```

is equal to:

```
let images: Object[] = [];
```

But using `Object` is too generic, you can be more specific:

```
let strings: Array<string> = [];
let numbers: Array<number> = [];

interface MyInterface {}
class MyClass1 implements MyInterface {}
class MyClass2 implements MyInterface {}

let arr: Array<MyInterface> = [];
arr.push(new MyClass1());
arr.push(new MyClass2());
```

You can use generics when you define your interfaces and classes:

```
interface MyInterface<T> {
    value: T;
}

let obj: MyInterface<string> = { value: "string" };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an empty array of objects.

It's just another way of writing this:

```
image: Object[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called *parametric polymorphism*. `Array` is a *type constructor*, and `Object` is the argument for that type constructor. `<>` are just the way type arguments for type constructors are denoted, the same way `()` denote value arguments for functions.